# How to change the picture in ImageView by clicking button?

Tags: android

There is one button in my app, which changes content on screen. Can I make this button change picuture in ImageView from array with pictures by clicking it?

Comment: Sure you can. What are you having problems with?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen can you help me write this code? I haven't find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
    final int[] images = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
    };
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView yourImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            yourImageView.setImageResource(images[0]);
        }
    });
```

This is one sulotion. Replace "yourButton" and "yourImageView" with your elements.

(Code not tested yet)
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. It's working. But I have problem, in onClick i also use "startActivity(getIntent());" and in the new Activity array starts anew :(